# Is there a way to call the getAlias name in Google App Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The issue is— emails are being sent from an alias [cs@example.com], and the name displayed in the inbox is cs (user), not the actual name— Example Support.

A possible solution is of course using the options `GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {from: alias[0], name: 'Example Support'})`, however, would there be a get option to keep it as a variable— like `getName`?

This is a stripped down version of the current code which works, but isn't ideal(‍♀️):

```
function myFunction() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var sent = 'SENT';

  for (var i = 2;i<=lastrow;i++){

    var email = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    var subject = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    var body = sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
    var status = sheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue();

    var alias = GmailApp.getAliases();
    var support = alias[0];
    var accounting = alias[1];
    var name1 = 'Example Support';
    var name2 = 'Example Accounting';

    if (status == 'support') {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {from: support, name: name1});
      sheet.getRange(i, 7).setValue(sent); 
      SpreadsheetApp.flush
      } else if (status == 'accounting') {
        GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {from: accounting, name: name2});
        sheet.getRange(i, 7).setValue(sent); 
        SpreadsheetApp.flush
        }
   }
}
```

Would you know of a possibility? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try using the Gmail API, specifically https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/list

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks, that's defenitely it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is only possible with the Gmail Advanced Google Services.

**Important!** First enable Gmail in **Resources > Advanced Google Services.** Then follow instructions for enabling the API in you script's GCP project.

To use your code as an example:

```
...
var support = alias[0]
...
if (status == 'support') {
  var aliasName = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.get(me, support).displayName
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {from: support, name: aliasName});
  sheet.getRange(i, 7).setValue(sent); 
  SpreadsheetApp.flush
}
```

Adjust your other if statement similarly.